# Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10 boot problem

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, uefi, windows-8

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my computer that had Windows 8 pre-installed. I used the instructions on this page:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
l
After following the instructions through to the end, and having run Boot Repair twice, I am still unable to load Windows 8 from Grub. I am, however, able to load it from BIOS.

Here is the boot info: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1567295/

Any suggestions to fix this would be greatly appreciated. While loading Windows from the BIOS is workable, it is certainly not ideal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the 2 `Windows UEFI` and the 2 `Windows Boot UEFI` entries of your GRUB menu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I could fix this by simply turning off secure boot in the BIOS.